# Why docker containers sometimes see each other and sometimes not?

Tags: docker

This is my `docker-composey.yml` and the only thing that is changed is the name of the brand (for the sake of privacy):

```
version: "3.9"
services:
    database:
        image: mariadb:latest
        container_name: ProjectDatabases
        hostname: database
        volumes:
            - /Temp/Project/Databases:/var/lib/mysql
        environment:
            - MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD=KlsIghYnx
        ports:
            - 55617:3306
        logging:
            driver: none
        # restart: always
        networks:
            - ProjectNetwork
    adminer:
        image: adminer
        container_name: ProjectAdminer
        # restart: always
        logging:
            driver: none
        ports:
            - 41412:8080
        environment:
            - ADMINER_DEFAULT_SERVER=database
        networks:
            - ProjectNetwork
    pma:
        image: phpmyadmin
        container_name: ProjectPma
        restart: always
        logging:
            driver: none
        ports:
            - 34964:80
        environment: 
            - PMA_HOST=database     
        networks:
            - ProjectNetwork
networks:
    ProjectNetwork:
        name: ProjectNetwork
        driver: bridge
```

It's a real `docker-compose.yml` file from our development environment.

The problem is that, sometimes phpMyAdmin sees the `database` container, and sometimes it does not see it.

I change nothing, stop the containers, rerun them and they connect and I can see my databases in phpMyAdmin.

Then I stop the containers, still change nothing and rerun them and this time they don't see each other.

This is completely intermittent.

When they don't see each other, I get an interactive bash from MariaDB using `docker exec -it ProjectDatabases bash` and use `mariadb -pPassword` to connect to the database engine and it works and I can query my data.

However, when I get an interactive bash from phpMyAdmin, the `telnet database 3306` gets stuck.

What can be wrong?

Comment: The `pma` container does not `depends_on: [database]`; is it possible that `pma` is just starting up first and `database` doesn't exist yet?

Comment: @DavidMaze, that's a good point. Yet when I can't `telnet database 3306` from inside the `pma` container, at that point the `database` container is up and running and fully functional and I can connect to MariaDB using `maria -pPassword`.